# How to turn JSON file into dataframe ('tibble')

Tags: r, json, binding, jsonlite, fromjson

I have downloaded some data from a platform and would like to convert it into a tibble I can manipulate in R. I have tried doing this, but continue coming up with errors.
The structure of my JSON file is as follows

```
List of 7
 $ TimeSeries     :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  7 variables:
  ..$ UniqueId          : chr [1:3] "0a87d824b33b45a594a29968549c0a07" "959696fb9f5f44d98cf463c96fb7225d" "ea45700060f84899928cfc7b49348795"
  ..$ Identifier        : chr [1:3] "O2 (Dis).ODO Conc@GRDA/Pensacola Dam REW" "O2 (Dis).ODO Conc@GRDA/Pensacola Dam LEW" "O2 (Dis).ODO Conc@GRDA/Pensacola Dam CEN"
  ..$ Parameter         : chr [1:3] "O2 (Dis)" "O2 (Dis)" "O2 (Dis)"
  ..$ Label             : chr [1:3] "ODO Conc" "ODO Conc" "ODO Conc"
  ..$ Unit              : chr [1:3] "mg/l" "mg/l" "mg/l"
  ..$ LocationIdentifier: chr [1:3] "GRDA/Pensacola Dam REW" "GRDA/Pensacola Dam LEW" "GRDA/Pensacola Dam CEN"
  ..$ InterpolationType : chr [1:3] "InstantaneousValues" "InstantaneousValues" "InstantaneousValues"
 $ TimeRange      :List of 2
  ..$ StartTime: chr "2021-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+00:00"
  ..$ EndTime  : chr "2022-01-01T00:00:00.0000001+00:00"
 $ NumPoints      : int 0
 $ Points         : list()
 $ ResponseVersion: int 1
 $ ResponseTime   : chr "2023-07-05T16:26:47.9875745+00:00"
 $ Summary        : chr "Produced by AQUARIUS Time-Series Software.\r\nThe accuracy and reliability of this data is not guaranteed.  Aqu"| __truncated__
```

I would like to come out with a df that has the Date, Timestamp, and Value associated with each of the three locations in one dataframe.

Something like this.

[image]

I've tried using 'purrr' and 'tidyjson', unnesting the json file, and EVERYTHING on stackoverflow,  but continue to get either parsing errors or character string errors.

The code I have originally is this

```r
source("timeseries_client.R")
timeseries$connect("https://owrbaqts.aquaticinformatics.net","myusername","mypassword")

json<- timeseries$getTimeSeriesData(c("O2 (Dis).ODO Conc@GRDA/Pensacola Dam REW",
                                      "O2 (Dis).ODO Conc@GRDA/Pensacola Dam LEW",
                                      "O2 (Dis).ODO Conc@GRDA/Pensacola Dam CEN"),
                                        queryFrom = "2021-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                                        queryTo = "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z")

str(json)
jsondf<-as.data.frame(json)
```

Comment: What errors are you actually coming up with? What does your data actually look like?

Comment: > jsondf<-as.data.frame(json)
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 1, 0
Error in exists(cacheKey, where = .rs.CachedDataEnv, inherits = FALSE) : 
  invalid first argument
Error in if (maxRows != -1 && nrow(data) > maxRows) data <- head(data,  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: You can't give `NULL` to `row.names`. It wants a `TRUE` or `FALSE`

Comment: I'm pretty new to RStudio and have never worked with JSON files. What would you suggest to try?

Comment: You're giving an argument a NULL that is wanting a TRUE or FALSE. Try changing the NULL to FALSE. You didn't share any code so I can only make assumptions.

Comment: source("timeseries_client.R")

timeseries$connect("https://owrb-aqts.aquaticinformatics.net","myusername","mypassword")

json<- timeseries$getTimeSeriesData(c("O2 (Dis).ODO Conc@GRDA/Pensacola Dam REW", "O2 (Dis).ODO Conc@GRDA/Pensacola Dam LEW","O2 (Dis).ODO Conc@GRDA/Pensacola Dam CEN"),
                                        queryFrom = "2021-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                                        queryTo = "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z")

Comment: and then the jsondf<- as.data.frame(json)

Comment: Format your code above in your question. Its hard to read when placed in a comment

Comment: Posted as an edit

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Rather copy and paste the code directly.

Comment: code posted directly

Comment: You already got an example JSON response (as you posted the structure). Why not just provide this sample in a reproducible way (using `dput`), your expected output (`dput` again) and edit the original question to result in a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ? At the same time you could check whether it's only the misspelled URL in your question that breaks the code.